# asp.net form controls are unreadable when in a jQuery dialog, how do you fix it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-dialog

I've got a prickly one. I have an asp.net web forms page. In the page I have a div tag that I've set to be used as a jQuery dialog. In the div is some jQuery controls. I get the dialog to open up and clicking on one of the buttons commences postback. When the page was posting back the code-behind hasn't been reading the values in the controls. Of course a little delving into the html reveals that the dialog takes my div and moves it to the bottom of the html page OUTSIDE my asp.net form tag. Urk!

How the hell do I get around this?

Not that it really helps the situation by my dialog code is here:

```
 $("#dialog-copy").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Yes': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $("[id*=btnCopy]")[0].click();
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $(":button:contains('Yes')").addClass("blue");
        }
    });
     $("[id*=btnCopy]").live('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-copy").dialog('open');
     });
```

And a typical div tag (that is moved to outside my form tag) is looking like this:

```
<div id="dialog-copy" style="DISPLAY: none" title="Copy Schedule">
    <p>Please enter a schedule number:</p>
    <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txtSchNo"></asp:Textbox>
</div>
```

Clicking 'Yes' fires the button that calls the postback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known issue, you have to append it to the form like this and your normal .NET controls can postback:

```
    open: function () {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        $(":button:contains('Yes')").addClass("blue");
    }
```

UPDATE for newer versions of jQuery:

```
   $('#yourDIv').dialog({
        .....,
        appendTo: $('form'),        
       ....

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your dialog button function add a hidden field to the form with the correct name, i.e., using the input in the dialog itself for reference, before it submits the form.

```
    buttons: {
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Yes': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $('#dialog-copy').find('input').each( function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="'
                                   + $this.attr('name')
                                   + '" value="'
                                   + $this.val() + '" />');
            });
            $("[id*=btnCopy]")[0].click();
        }
    },
```

Comment: The new input added from client side would again be invisible to the server-side .NET code. Is it not?

Comment: @FloydPink - not if it has the same name as an existing input on the form.  It should be reconstructed just as if it hadn't been removed from the form in the first place.  When it's posted back it has no idea what actual DOM element it came from.

Comment: Ah, okay. It would need the id attribute as well copied over from the original input then.

Comment: @FloydPink - no, the id attribute isn't used when it is posted back. The only thing that matters is the name of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Keep a regular html input within the dialog and just before clicking the postback button move the value within the html text input to the asp:TextBox or for that matter even a asp:HiddenInput.

Like:

```
$("#dialog-copy").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Yes': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $('input[id$=_txtSchNo').val($('#dummy').val());
                $("[id*=btnCopy]")[0].click();
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $(":button:contains('Yes')").addClass("blue");
        }
    });
     $("[id*=btnCopy]").live('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-copy").dialog('open');
     });
```

And the markup:

```
<form>
....
<asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txtSchNo"></asp:Textbox>
...
</form>
<div id="dialog-copy" style="DISPLAY: none" title="Copy Schedule">
    <p>Please enter a schedule number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="dummy" />
</div>
```