# ASP.NET WebApp don't work with Custom Template (from store)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have jQuery based template from themeforest and 
i building on this ASP.NET Web Application.

But i have a problem, when my javascripts files
from template are included, my asp.net things
don't work how should, eg. dropdownlist events
not rising... When i comment javascript templates
file then everything works fine.

Someone can help me solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many jQuery UI elements (dialog, for example) are rendered at the end of the BODY tag.  This means their contents are moved outside the FORM tag, and are thus ignored by ViewState.  This will prevent their associated events from being triggered (and will prevent their updated data from making it back to the code-behind at all).

If you use firebug to examine the rendered HTML, you should be able to confirm whether this is the root cause of your problem.

If so, see [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591601/asp-net-form-controls-are-unreadable-when-in-a-jquery-dialog-how-do-you-fix-it) for a resolution / workaround.  HTH